# INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Array subscript out of bounds

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I'm querying a column with a variable length JSON array.

```
select col.pages[1].name, col.pages[2].name from assoc
```

I get this error when there is only one value in the array.

```
INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Array subscript out of bounds
```

How do I prevent this error if there's only one value?

Answer (score 16):

Athena is based on Presto 0.172. You can wrap your expression in Presto's [`try`](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/conditional.html#try):

```
SELECT try(some_array[2]) FROM ...
```